# How can you tell which port number an existing Database Connection is configured for?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase

I have a database connection to a postgresql database on a non-default port, 5433.

I specify `TESTDB,5433` as the instance and I can connect with no errors.
[image]

If I open that connection properties again, the Instance is displayed with no port configured:
[image]

When I hit cancel and the double-click the connection, I connect successfully to the 5433 port (confirmed by checking the server status of the 5433 and seeing the incoming connection). Even after hitting `OK` on the Instance without a port...the connection still connects to 5433.  Only after expliciting specifying `TESTDB,5432` can I switch back to the 5432.

Since both instances have the same data schema (and often the same data), how would an ArcGIS user know which instance he or she is connected to?

Comment: go to the server configuration file and the port is likely configured in there. It has been a while since I had a postgres installation but I think it is config.conf in the etc folder

Comment: my bad. maybe postgresql.conf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187438/want-to-change-pgsql-port

Comment: The postgresql.conf is server-side and I already know what ports I'm running, both 5432 and 5433 (and 5434 and 5435 but those don't have the same databases on them).  How would a user who doesn't have administrative access to the database server, know the connection after it has been created.

Comment: @JayCummins, I experience the same issue as you and the only solution that I could find is to create a Python add-in and add a new right-click context menu item for the enterprise database in ArcMap for all users (so they right-click the db, click Show port and then a alert window is shown with the port number). The code behind is just `arcpy.Describe()` object with method `connectionProperties` and property `instance`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've mitigated this issue by:

1. Put the port number in the name of the connection file as soon as
   its created.
2. Add a [view](http://hastebin.com/uhobabepul.sql) that will report system info--the view will be
   visible in  ArcCatalog, so you can see which port you are connected
   on:

[image]

[image]

```
CREATE VIEW public.vw_sysinfo AS 
 SELECT inet_server_port() AS inet_server_port, 
    current_database() AS current_database, pg_backend_pid() AS pg_backend_pid, 
    "current_user"() AS "current_user", version() AS version, 
    postgis_version() AS postgis_version;
```